# Will NSA's Utah Data Center be able to handle and process five zettabytes of data?

Tags: computers, nsa

The claim I want to have examined is

> The NSA's Utah Data Center will be able to handle and process five zettabytes of data.

I think that "zettabytes" is much too big. Even one Exabyte might be to much to store (not even to speak about the possibility to process such an amount of data).

### Sources

> The Utah Data Center, also known as the Intelligence Community
>   Comprehensive National Cybersecurity Initiative Data Center, is a
>   data storage facility for the United States Intelligence Community
>   that is designed to store extremely large amounts of data.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah_Data_Center)

> The National Security Agency is building a data centre that could
>   potentially hold **yottabytes** of data.

Source: [cnet.co.uk](http://crave.cnet.co.uk/gadgets/nsa-to-store-yottabytes-in-utah-data-centre-49304118/)

> The estimated power of those computing resources in Utah is so massive
>   it requires use of a little-known unit of storage space: the
>   **zettabyte**. Cisco quantifies a zettabyte as the amount of data that
>   would fill 250 billion DVDs.
>   [...] The NSA's Utah Data Center will be able to handle and process
>   **five zettabytes** of data, according to William Binney, a former NSA
>   technical director turned whistleblower. Binney's calculation is an
>   estimate. An NSA spokeswoman says the actual data capacity of the
>   center is classified.

Source: [npr.org](http://www.npr.org/2013/06/10/190160772/amid-data-controversy-nsa-builds-its-biggest-data-farm)

```
Space(1 DVD) = 4.7 GB
Space(250 * 10^9 DVDs) = 250*10^9*4.7 GB = 1175 EB = 1.175 ZB
```

As those numbers roughly match, I guess it's not a simple typo on npr.org.

But 1 YB = 1000 ZB, so this doesn't match.

Also: The biggest storage device I could find on Amazon with [this search](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_st?bbn=1292110011&qid=1372827317&rh=n:172282,n%3a!493964,n:541966,n:1292110011&sort=-price) was [Quantum StorNext AEL500 Archive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006M2QHL6) for $143,918.20. It can store 399 TB. This means `399 TB / $143,918.20 = $0.36 per GigaByte`

So for `5 ZB` we would need `(5 * 10^21 Byte) / (399 * 10^12 Byte) = 1.253*10^7`. That would mean you would have to pay about `$143,918.20*1.253*10^7 = $1.803 trillion  (US dollars)`. But:

> The U.S. Army Corps of Engineers broke ground this week on a massive
>   new National Security Agency cyber intelligence center in Utah.
>   Located at Camp Williams, 25 miles south of Salt Lake City, the **$1.2
>   billion facility** — officially known as the Utah Data Center — will be
>   responsible for collecting and aggregating incoming intelligence data.

Source: [defensesystems.com](http://defensesystems.com/Articles/2011/01/07/NSA-spy-cyber-intelligence-data-center-Utah.aspx)

### Estimates

Even after searching for a device with lowest dollar-per-gigabyte ratio, I didn't find anything cheaper than $0.05/GB. This means you could come down to 250 billion US-$, which is still much too much.

Even more problematic might be the power consumption.

### Questions that might lead to an answer

Did I make any mistake? Could this eventually be true (Whats hot in science about data storages?) Which capacity do big companies like Google / Facebook / Dropbox have? How much can Wikipedia (especially commons) store?

### Storage systems

> Provide up to 900 PB of automated, low-cost storage

[IBM System Storage TS3500 Tape Library](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/storage/tape/ts3500/index.html)

### Problems of this question

- I thought "handle and process" would mean they have to store this amount of information, but the source doesn't say that
- It's not clear what "handle and process" exactly means. Especially throughput should be mentioned.

Comment: There is no meaningful claim here. “process” requires a  *measure of throughput*, not volume. “process X bytes” is meaningless, “process X bytes *per second* ” would be meaningful. Maybe the question was whether the centre can *store* this much data rather than process it? If so, that is a fundamentally different claim: processing doesn’t imply storage, and storing only implies processing in an intangible way.

Comment: Oh yeah - this might be 'interesting', in case you don't use "zettabytes" every day: https://xkcd.com/992

Comment: Missing from your price calculations are 1) the fact that the NSA would clearly be buying in bulk, which would likely reduce the per-unit price and 2) *the technology available to the general public, at whatever price range, is almost certainly not the same as the technology available to a maximum security clearance government agency*.

Comment: @Shadur "the technology available to the general public, at whatever price range, is almost certainly not the same as the technology available to a maximum security clearance government agency." - why do you think that?

Comment: @martinthoma http://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/ would be the quickest example, but what it boils down to is that you can usually rely on governments and military agencies to keep their shiniest toys close to their chest and not let the civilians play with them until they have something better for themselves.

Comment: @Shadur I think there is a big difference. Satellites are not used by many consumers and they are not produced by many organizations. In contrast, the urge to store large amounts of data have many companies. GPS was developed by the DoD and there are only alternatives by Russa, the EU and China. To get anything usable for global navigation is incredible expensive. But storage solutions are developed by many companies. Developing usable solutions is comparatively simple and cheap. Hence I don't think there are storage technologies available to NSA which are not available to the (wealthy) public

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer is highly speculative since the NSA has [not given any indication](http://www.npr.org/2013/06/10/190160772/amid-data-controversy-nsa-builds-its-biggest-data-farm) as to the capacity of the facility. Also, this is a very difficult question to digest because we have no indication of how much data they are seeking to actually store.

To examine the first claim that they process up to five zettabytes of data, this seems to be plausible. We know that the [Large Hadron Collider (LHC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider) is generating [one petabyte data per second](http://cacm.acm.org/news/110048-cern-experiments-generating-one-petabyte-of-data-every-second/fulltext) and storing twenty-five petabytes of data per year<sup>1</sup>. Using some simple math,

```
1 zettabyte = 1,048,576 petabytes
1,048,576 seconds = 12.1363 days

1 zettabyte every 12.1363 days 
or about 30 zettabytes of data a year
```

According to [Cisco's forecasting](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/solutions/collateral/ns341/ns525/ns537/ns705/ns827/white_paper_c11-481360_ns827_Networking_Solutions_White_Paper.html), the world is on track to have 1.4 zettabytes of global [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) traffic per year by the end of 2017. So anyone that is engaged in processing that data data would need to have zettabyte processing capability and given that the LHC already has it, we can conclude that it is likely that an agency such as the NSA would design that into the system. Also, that just includes the IP traffic and other voice and data communications that travel via other systems.

With regards to storage of data, the common number seems to be five zettabytes so we will examine that. The capability for exabyte storage system already exists commercially. IBM manufactures the [System Storage TS3500 Tape Library](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/storage/tape/ts3500/index.html) offers up to 2.7 exabytes of data, specifically,

> Up to 180 PB compressed with 3592 extended capacity cartridges per
>   library, up to 2.7 EB compressed per complex

The physical footprint of a single frame is 70.9 in. H × 30.8 in. W × 47.7 in. D (1,800 mm × 782 mm × 1,212 mm) or a footprint of about 10.2 sq.ft. (0.9 sq.m.) which puts it in range of most [42U rack dimensions](http://www.42u.com/42U-cabinets.htm). In order to reach the full 2.7 exabytes, 15 libraries are needed, each of which would need 16 frames which gives us 2,448 sq.ft (227.4 sq.m.). The amount of additional space needed due to airflow and system access is [fairly complex](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ts3500tl/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.storage.ts3500.doc/ipg_3584_sc1specs.html), so excluding that from the equation,

```
2.7 exabytes per complex with a footprint of 2,448 sq.ft.
1 zettabyte = 1024 exabytes
1024 / 2.7 = 379.2 systems, so say 380 systems
380 * 2,448 sq.ft = 930,240 sq.ft per zettabyte
```

This gives us about 4,651,200 sq.ft. (432,110.62 sq.m) for the 5 zettabytes figure normally given. Even storage of a single zettabyte using the systems appears to be outside of the bounds of [100,000 sq.ft. for the data halls](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2012/03/ff_nsadatacenter/all/1) that the Utah Data Center will have let alone the 1 to 1.5 million sq.ft. size given for the complex as a whole.

Based upon this, the claims that it will be storing five zettabytes of data is dubious; however, these calculations are based upon a commercially available system so it is possible that they have a smaller footprint for what they are using. That said though, even storage of a single zettabyte is likely an extreme stretch given what is on the commercial market. However, in [2010 IBM Research announced a new record](http://www.zurich.ibm.com/news/10/storage.html) in tape storage with a potential capacity of 35 terabytes of uncompressed storage per cartridge. The current high-end offering from IBM is the [3592 Tape Cartridge](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/storage/media/3592/index.html) which stores up to 4 terabytes.

The aforementioned TS3500 Tape Library holds up to 225,000 tape cartridges so if each of the cartridges was capable of 35 terabytes the total TS3500 complex storage would be about 7.51 exabytes of storage. If we apply these updated values to the previous calculations,

```
7.51 exabytes per complex with a footprint of 2,448 sq.ft.
1 zettabyte = 1024 exabytes
1024 / 7.51 = 136.4 systems, so say 137 systems
137 * 2,448 sq.ft = 335,376 sq.ft per zettabyte
```

So even with that the data halls are still too small to store a single zettabyte although we are now into the range where the complex as a whole might be capable of storing one to two zettabytes under ideal conditions.

Granted does require the use of tape data storage [which is very slow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_drive); however, without knowing exactly what the NSA is doing with the data we can't speculate if they are concerned with access speeds or not. Furthermore, [metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata) indexing techniques mean that the raw data may not be needed for most processing so the latency involved with tape storage may not be a concern for the NSA. We already know that they have [large scale metadata databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAINWAY) so it is quite likely that they could be using such techniques for [working with tape data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAINWAY).

So in summary, the claims as to the amount of data that could be stored and processed are **currently implausible** given the size of the facility and the currently know state of the art and commercially available systems. However, the claim that the could be processing five zettabytes of data is **plausible** given the shear amount of data traffic that exists in the world and we don't know how they are processing the data. If they use curiosity examination followed by discarding of uninteresting data like the LHC then it is possible and their actual data storage requirements would be reduced as well.

---

1. In the case of the LHC, they discard most of the data as "uninteresting" as opposed to actually storing it.
2. Even if the data halls are only 100,000 sq.ft. there still should be sufficient space although it might be less likely given that we don't know the configuration of the buildings.

Comment: Even if they discard the data as uninteresting, they are still "handling and processing" it.

Comment: Utah complex might be 1mln sq.ft., but it's said that 900,000 sq.ft. of that are administrative and support buildings, while only 100,000 sq.ft. are actual datacenter

Comment: Also, LHC example is just wrong. The do generate that much data from experiments,  but the do not claim, that data from experiments is processed in real time.

Comment: @vartec the use case for this facility would be to do real-time analysis of data as it comes in, then archive the data for later retrieval. They'll run Hadoop and such on the stuff they suck up today, but data from last month is only going to be accessed if they decide you're suspicious and want to take a closer look at your activity history. It's all just caching layers :)

Comment: Also it seems that you didn't quite interpret tape library capacity/dimensions properly. 16 frames is one library, not the whole complex. Whole 2.7EB complex is 15 libraries of 16 frames each.

Comment: @rob: you did. Calculating CERN's processing capacity as if they were processing data in real time. They don't. http://home.web.cern.ch/about/computing

Comment: Ok, I retract my previous downvote comment. In fact it's -1 for 15-fold error on tape library size and complete misunderstanding of CERN's datacenter throughput.

Comment: @vartec Good catch on the complex sizes, I've updated the answer and conclusions accordingly.

Comment: @vartec The use of LHC still seems valid though since part of the problem that people have with zettabytes is if that much data is even being generated in the world.

Comment: @rob: the thing with LHC is that experiments last fractions of a second, yet the results are analysed at CERN for months. So they can capture a burst of data, but they are nowhere near a sustained throughput of such a proportions.

Comment: @vartec That conflicts with what CREN says they do - http://home.web.cern.ch/about/updates/2013/04/animation-shows-lhc-data-processing - in short, they filter the data that is coming off the detectors and discard most of it. There is then a second pass that discards even more of the data. After that they send the "interesting" data off for the analysis that takes longer. Personally I wouldn't be too surprised if the NSA setup is similar to what CERN is doing for LHC data.

Comment: @rob: it they'd disregard data, they why store zettabytes of it?

Comment: @vartec The NSA or the LHC? As near as I can tell CERN only stores petabytes of data annually and nobody has definitively proven that the NSA stores the five zettabytes that people claimed. They might be capable of storing a zettabyte in Utah (I'd likely speculate they are between a combination of tape, compression, deduplication, etc.) but five zettabytes seems outside the current state of the art given the square footage.

Comment: The surface area for the facility isn't the entire story. Using multiple floors, basements, etc. it can easily be multiplied. So if they have 100.000 sq.ft. surface area for storage, and store on 3 floors and 2 basement levels, that's half a million square feet already.

Comment: @jwenting I know, but since I don't see them disclosing that sort of information I don't see how that could reliablity be taken into account. Personally I'd be surprised if there weren't multiple sub-levels to the data halls.

Comment: @rob: what would be the point of having sub-levels if you're building in remote area where land is cheap? Their budget is $1.2bn, not $1.2tn.

Comment: @vartec Well, deception.  I see your point, and don't quite agree with Rob about the likelihood, but it's conceivable.   Note that during the Cold War, there were several instances of designing bases in such a way - so that even if the other side had satellite pictures, they wouldn't really know everything about (or scale of, even) the facility.

Comment: @hunter2 I guess it depends upon how you are defining sublevels. Given the buildings I'd be surprised if there wasn't at least a basement for infrastructure, but the question is how many are below that.

Comment: @rob, I agree that "at least a basement for infrastructure" is likely, and that "multiple sub-levels to the data halls" is possible. I thought you meant that you'd consider the latter not only possible but *likely* ("be surprised if there weren't multiple sub-levels") ... meh, semantics

Answer (score 3):

There are several claims about extremely huge data storage capacity in Utah, like "*The NSA's Utah Data Center will be able to handle and process five zettabytes of data.*" (yotta = 1000 zetta = 1M exa = 1 billion peta = 1 trillion tera)

Many of them comes from wrong estimations from William Binney (a former NSA technical director), according to NPR: http://www.npr.org/2013/06/10/190160772/amid-data-controversy-nsa-builds-its-biggest-data-farm

> The NSA's Utah Data Center will be able to handle and process five zettabytes of data, **according to William Binney**, a former NSA technical director turned whistleblower. Binney's calculation is an **estimate**. An NSA spokeswoman says the actual data capacity of the center is classified.

Here is full photocopy of Binney declaration for the CASE NO. CV-08-04373-JSW, from September 28, 2012: https://www.eff.org/sites/default/files/filenode/binneydeclaration.pdf - page 4 lines 18-26:

```
18   11. A futher notable development has been the NSA's public announcement in October 
19  2009 that it was building a massive, $1.2 billion digital storage facility in Ft. Williams, Utah.
20  According to some reports, the Utah facility will eventually have a data storage capacity measured 
21  in yottabytes (10**24 bytes). Even if the Utah facility were to have no more than the amount of data
22  storage that is presently commercially available, then one would expect the data storage to be in the
23  range of multiples of ten exebytes (10**18 bytes). See www.cleversafe.com. (According to 
24  Cleversafe, its ten exebyte storage solution fills no more than tho hundred square feet).
```

Forbes checked his estimations and found huge error in how much space will Cleversafe's solution needs for 10 exabytes:
http://www.forbes.com/sites/kashmirhill/2013/07/24/blueprints-of-nsa-data-center-in-utah-suggest-its-storage-capacity-is-less-impressive-than-thought/

> Blueprints Of NSA's Ridiculously Expensive Data Center In Utah Suggest It Holds Less Info Than Thought, 7/24/2013
>
> Binney gave the 5 zettabyte estimate to NPR and also included it in an affidavit filed in Jewel vs. NSA ...
>
> His estimate is based on the assumption the facility might offer equipment like that developed by Cleversafe. The company says it has a 10-exabyte data storage system that involves portable data centers with 21 racks each
>
> Binney read this as meaning that 21 racks could hold 10 exabytes, and assumed an efficient rack size of 4 square feet, ...
>
> **he misread the Cleversafe marketing materials**. They actually say that 560 portable data centers of 21 racks each (or 11,760 racks) can hold 10 exabytes. ...
>
> Chris Gladwin, founder of Cleversafe, says that in January of 2012, 10 exabytes of storage system would have needed “about 2 million square feet.”

So, marketing speech of Cleversafe leads ex NSA technical director to the very wrong estimations.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the interpretation of what *handle and process five zettabytes of data* really means:

1. having 5ZB readily available for online processing?
2. having 5ZB in off-line archive, while having only meta-data readily available for on-line processing?
3. having 5ZB incoming traffic, discharging most of it, storing and processing only interesting stuff?

### On-line storage

If you're going to build something as big as NSA datacenter, instead of buying readily available hardware, you might go for custom builds using big data industry standards.

Facebook's [Open Compute Storage](http://www.opencompute.org/) specifies [Open Vault storage](http://www.opencompute.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Open-Vault-Storage-Specification-v0.5.pdf), which is designed to house 30 3.5" HDDs in 2U case. Which with currently available HDDs would mean density of 120TB per 2U.

You can put 21 of these in one standard [42U high 19" rack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19-inch_rack), meaning you'd have 2520TB per rack.

Each rack having a base of about 0.62m². Adding some very minimum clearance, 1m² per rack would be the very lowball estimate.

That's assuming that you'd be willing to have machines custom build for your datacenter. Otherwise it's off the shelf hardware. For example [Dell PowerVault MD1200](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/powervault-md1200/fs) configured with [12 4TB SATA drives costs $11,254.21;](http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=bvcwlk4&model_id=powervault-md1200&c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04) That of course is retail price, which bulk orders you get hefty discounts. Similarly, you could get a cloud server such as [PowerEdge C6145](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-c6145/pd), which can also be equipped with 12 4TB SATA drives. They don't provide they pricing on-line, but if I remember correctly, that kind of setup it'd be around $15-20K.

Both of above give you density of 48TB per 2U. Which means 1004TB per rack.

[NSA Utah datacenter is reported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah_Data_Center) to have 10,000m² dedicated to servers (100,000m² including administrative and support buildings). So really, really high ball estimate would be that they could theoretically squeeze 25EB of cloud storage in there.
That's only 0.5% of 5ZB.

### Off-line storage

If you're considering offline archiving of data, you might use tape libraries. It's not typically used in Big Data, but then again, NSA isn't typical Big Data company.

Problem is, that even with highest density [IBM System Storage TS3500 Tape Library](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/storage/tape/ts3500/index.html), you can store 180PB per library, which has footprint of at least 15m². Which means about 420,000m² would be needed just for the tape libraries. Whole NSA Utah complex is estimated to have "1 million or 1.5 million square feet" (93,000m²-149,000m²), but it's also been said that it's *"100,000 square feet (9,300m²) of data center space and greater than 900,000 square feet (83,600m²) of technical support and administrative space"* ([source](http://www.wired.com/threatlevel/2012/03/ff_nsadatacenter/all/1)). Purpose of the buildings might be kept secret or intentionally misleading, external dimensions cannot. So clearly there is no way to squeeze 5ZB of tape archive there, even if buildings said to be administrative are actually purposed for tape archive.

### Meta-data

So let's assume that even if you'd manage to somehow archive 5ZB of raw data, as I've calculated above even if you'd use all your datacenter space for on-line processing, that would mean you're storing only 5KB of metadata for each 1MB of data. While for media files that seems more than enough, I really doubt you can achieve ratio anywhere near that for emails, chats, text messages, tweets etc. Of course they might filter out information they've not interested in and not store any metadata related to that information. But in that case there is no point in archiving that information off-line, because you don't have path of access — you don't have metadata pointing to it, nor can you mine the data that is archived on tapes.

### Throughput

Assuming that it's 5ZB per year, that's a sustained throughput of 570PB per day, or 160TB per second. Leaving apart computing power needed to process that, question is how that data would be transported there? Current internet infrastructure isn't anywhere nearly ready for that kind of traffic. Three of the biggest [internet exchange points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_exchange_points_by_size) are located in Europe having maximum throughput of 2.2TBps, 2.1TBps and 1.6TBps respectively. US is trailing way behind with top US only exchanges having only 0.28TBps and 0.25TBps, another one, Equinix has total of 1.4TBps across 12 countries on 4 continents. In other words it's completely infeasible to push 5ZB per year into a datacenter, especially in such a remote location. Nor, as you can see, necessary, even if you'd want to process all of Internet traffic.

### Conclusion

1. having 5ZB readily available for online processing? 
    **Physically impossible**
2. having 5ZB in off-line archive, while having only meta-data readily available for on-line processing? **Not possible with current technology and sizes of the buildings as reported**
3. having 5ZB incoming traffic, discharging most of it, storing and processing only interesting stuff? **Regardless of processing, it's just not possible to have that amount of incoming traffic**

---

HighScalability.com has a guest post ["PRISM: The Amazingly Low Cost Of ­Using BigData To Know More About You In Under A Minute"](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/7/1/prism-the-amazingly-low-cost-of-using-bigdata-to-know-more-a.html) by BugSense Founder/CTO Jon Vlachogiannis and Head of Infrastructure at BugSense Panagiotis Papadomitsos.

They calculate for storage needed as 3.75EB.

> ### DATA
>
> Facebook: 500 TB/day * 30 = 1.5 PT/month ([source](http://gigaom.com/2012/08/22/facebook-is-collecting-your-data-500-terabytes-a-day/))
>
> Twitter: 8 TB/day * 30 = 240 TB/month 8 TB/day ([source](http://www.slideshare.net/raffikrikorian/twitter-by-the-numbers))
>
> Email/Other info: 193PT/month Google says 24 PB per day (2008). Five
>   years later lets assume this is 8 times bigger = 192 PB. Now, real
>   user information is 1/3 = 64 PT/day ([source](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1327452.1327492))
>
> Mobile traffic/machine­to­machine exchanges/vehicles etc: 4000 TB per
>   day = 117 PB/month ([source](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1327452.1327492))
>
> Total Data =~312PB month
>
> ### Hardware Costs
>
> The prices below correspond to renting off­the­shelf servers from
>   commercial high­end datacenters (considering the data will be stored
>   in a distributed filesystem architecture such as HDFS). This is a
>   worst case scenario that does not include potential discounts due to
>   renting such a high volume of hardware and traffic or acquiring the
>   aforementioned hardware (which incurs a higher initial investment but
>   lower recurring costs) . The hardware configuration used for
>   calculating costs in this case study is comprised of a 2U chassis,
>   dual Intel Hexa­core processors, 16 GB of RAM, 30 TB of usable space
>   combined with hardware­level redundancy (RAID5).
>
> We’ll be needing about 20K servers, put into 320 46U racks. Cost for
>   the server hardware is calculated to be about €7.5M / month (including
>   servers for auxiliary services). Cost for the racks, electricity and
>   traffic is calculated to be about €0.5M / month (including auxiliary
>   devices and networking equipment).
>
> **Total hardware cost per year for 3.75 EB of data storage: €168M**

---

And comparison with Facebook:

> It’s no secret that Facebook stores a **lot of data — 100 petabytes** ([source](http://gigaom.com/2012/06/13/how-facebook-keeps-100-petabytes-of-hadoop-data-online/))

Comment: This assumes we know the storage technology that would be available to the NSA.

Comment: @Sancho: why wouldn't we? anything experimental would be a) ridiculously expensive b) had to made completely in US c) by government agencies. Unless you're thinking some alien technology from Rosewell...

Comment: *anything experimental would be a) ridiculously expensive b) had to made completely in US c) by government agencies.* Yes, this is what I'm thinking of, not aliens.

Comment: @Sancho: although WD and Seagate are US companies, they have foreign shareholders and HDDs themselves are not made in USA. So could they secretly create HDDs with few hundred times higher capacity secretly just for NSA? Or maybe IBM created special higher capacity tapes just for NSA? Would any company be willing to sacrifice it's business to please NSA and keep killer product of the market?

Comment: *So could they secretly create HDDs with few hundred times higher capacity secretly just for NSA?* I don't know. *Or maybe IBM created special higher capacity tapes just for NSA?* Maybe. *Would any company be willing to sacrifice it's business to please NSA and keep killer product of the market?* I don't know.

Comment: There is a way to make sense of and agree with the claim in the OP: 1) There is five zettabytes of data in the world, which the NSA must process; 2) The NSA will do that from/using their new data processing facility. That "160TB per second" of processing which you mention, for example, might be (and I assume it  is) distributed around the world, often co-located with the network switches or trunks which run the traffic. And, that data centre might be a/the back-end, storage, control, and operations centre for that (distributed) processing.

Comment: @ChrisW: while I could imagine that UK gov. would allow something like that, I see no way German or Dutch would go for it. And besides, the company operating the exchange would have to go for it.

Comment: @vartec The feds are famously attached to switches within the USA itself. And I read that [Cheltenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_Communications_Headquarters) watches the traffic going though satellites. Operating companies will install whatever surveillance back-doors are required by the national governments. Anyway, I assume that's how some of it actually works, more or less: it doesn't make as much sense, to me, to route all the raw traffic through Utah.

Comment: @ChrisW: NSA can easily bully US companies to comply, that's quite obvious. I don't think they'd be so effective in case of foreign company on foreign, non-UK, soil. GCHQ closely cooperating with NSA, that unfortunately is a fact.

Comment: Taking Germany and Holland, for example, there exists traffic between Amsterdam and Berlin. Either the NSA can access that traffic somehow, in which case that traffic is part of the alleged dataset to be processed, or they can't access it at all (in which case it isn't relevant to the question). Now, restricting the Gedanken experiment to the set of all data/traffic to which the NSA does have access, it's plausible that some/much/most of their processing/filtering would be done at the 'periphery' (of their network), at or near wherever their 'taps' are (into the public network).

Comment: I assume that all national governments are monitoring their own phone networks in some way: for example it was newsworthy a while back, that India wanted better surveillance access to the messages generated by Blackberry devices. Therefore I expect that most operating companies have legally required surveillance data taps and storage. How much of that all that data the NSA can access is (part of) the question.

Comment: Reports like [In 2008, Americans consumed ... 3.6 zettabytes and 10,845 trillion words, corresponding to 100,500 words and 34 gigabytes for an average person on an average day.](http://hmi.ucsd.edu/howmuchinfo_research_report_consum.php) suggest that the "five zettabytes of data" cited in the OP might be a short/sloppy way of saying, "the NSA's entire data set".

Comment: "So could they secretly create HDDs with few hundred times higher capacity secretly just for NSA?" Northrop secretly produced stealth bombers just for the USAF, Lockheed stealth fighters, there is a very long history of companies secretly producing things just for a government agency in their native country that they could have marketed commercially if it weren't classified high enough to disallow that.

Comment: @jwenting: fighter jets aren't exactly consumer goods, also while stealth technology, which doesn't have civilian application, was kept secret, other technologies, like for example digital fly-by-wire, were not.

Comment: @ChrisW: if it'd be filtered in peripheral location, that would mean that it is *not* handled and stored in Utah facility, which is what the question is about.

Comment: @vartec principle is the same. And a lot of those things were kept secret, for a time. being used in military applications for years or sometimes decades before being released to the general public.

Comment: @ChrisW: the way As for 3.6ZB figure is bit ridiculous. Eg. 200 ppl watching a movie in cinema is counted as *each* consuming equivalent in uncompressed full-HD video. Also playing video game is counted even more extreme, as if it was uncompressed video recorded in native resolution (meaning that someone playing on Retina display is counted as if consuming 2880×1800@60Hz uncompressed video)

Comment: @jwentig:  can you give a single example of computer or telecommunication technology, which was keep secret anytime in last 30-40 years?

Comment: @vartec That is a separate claim, for a separate question.

Comment: @jwenting: also, if you're thinking experimental technologies as in stealth planes, accumulated cost of B-2 is $2bn per unit. Whole NSA Utah datacenter, including construction, personnel etc. is budgeted for $1.2bn.

Answer (score 2):

Based on rough calculations done by Brewster Kahle who knows about storage from the Internet Archive, about 270 Petabytes (and $27M) is needed to store all US phone calls for a year. So, these numbers may be more in the order of magnitude for expectations of the Utah data center in the near term.
http://blog.archive.org/2013/06/15/cost-to-store-all-us-phonecalls-made-in-a-year-in-cloud-storage-so-it-could-be-datamined/